# Is there a way to set Google Voice as default tel protocol handler?

Tags: firefox, google-voice, protocol-handler

I would like to be able to click tel links in my web browser (Firefox 70.0.1) and have it launch voice.google.com, with the phone number populated in the dialer so that I can then dial the number via my phone (which also has Google Voice). Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 7):

As of 23 Feb 2022, Google provides instructions to [Use one-click dialing on Google Voice](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/11397414?hl=en)
.

Prior to that, in Chrome, I was able to register Google Voice to handle `tel:` links by running the following code via Developer Tools > Console.

```
window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler("tel", "https://voice.google.com/u/0/calls?a=nc,%s","phone");
```

Comment: Wow, for Brave (based on Chrome), I could not find how to do this anywhere. Even brave://settings/handlers?search=protocol+handlers didn't give an option. What worked was: open a tab to https://voice.google.com/u/0/messages . Then open the dev tools and run this in the console: `window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler("tel", "https://voice.google.com/u/0/calls?a=nc,%s","phone");` I accepted the prompt, and now brave://settings/handlers?search=protocol+handlers shows that `tel:` is handled by voice.google.com. Thanks!

Comment: Here I am again, and I was excited that this SuperUser answer appeared in my search results, and then I found myself saying "This commenter wrote a really helpful comment" and was pleasantly surprised to see it was my past self. Note-taking for the win.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE** I'm on a Mac but should work for Windows as well with some verbiage changes.

I've found a way to do this in Firefox without any extensions.

1. Type "about:support" in the search bar.
2. You'll have troubleshooting information displayed along with a grid titled "Application Basics"
3. Find the one labeled "Profile Folder" and click the "Show in Finder" button
4. In the window that opens, find the *handler.json* file and edit it using your preferred editor.
5. In the "schemes" section, add the following code (I placed mine after the "mailto" portion ensuring all the tabs lined up).

> 

```
  "tel":
    {
        "handlers":
        [
            {
                "name": "Google Voice",
                "uriTemplate": "https://voice.google.com/u/0/calls?a=nc,%s"
            }
        ],
    },
```

6. Save your changes, quit and reload your browser.

You may or may not be prompted to pick the application (mine gave me the option of Facetime or Google Voice), I picked Google Voice and "Remember this choice". It immediately opened a tab and proceeded to complete the call. When I reviewed the file again, there was an "action": 2 added. My guess would be due to my picking the 2nd option and "remember".

Screenshot included for your reference.

[image: handler.json code]

Comment: I think this is the exact answer that user ETL is looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to do that without adding a browser extension. Since I use Chromium, I used https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-voice-by-google/kcnhkahnjcbndmmehfkdnkjomaanaooo?hl=en

Firefox extensions for Google are [listed here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?platform=windows&q=Google%20Voice) but I did not find one offering click-to-dial into gVoice after searching through 31 screens of extensions.

Comment: Thanks for doing that research! I'll check out if that extension can be ported to Firefox via Chrome-Store-Foxified.

Comment: @ETL, if you found this answer useful please click on the up Arrow Head to the left of the beginning of the answer. When all is said and done give any answer provides information that solves your problem then please click the check mark at left